# Java method Point rot90()

Tags: java, math, coordinates, point

I am trying to figure out how to implement the following method in java;

** Point rot90()** *Query for a new Cartesian Point equivalent to this Cartesian point rotated by 90 degrees*

I have no idea how to go about creating this method.  However, I do believe that pulling the point (x,y) and outputting new point (y,x*-1) is equivalent to rotating 90 degrees. Basically the old y coordinate becomes the nee x coordinate and the new y coordinate is the old x coordinate multiplied by negative 1.  Any thoughts on how to set up this method would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

this is what I have so far

```
  public Point rot90(){
    Point rotated = new Point();
    rotated.yCoord = xCoord*-1;
    rotated.xCoord = yCoord;
    return rotated;
  }
```

I know this doesn't work as pointed out when I try to compile it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: But you already described how to set up this method. What more do you need to know?

Comment: I just need like a visual idea to wrap my head around the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs an argument.

```
public Point rot90(Point p){
  Point rotated = new Point();
  rotated.yCoord = -p.xCoord;
  rotated.xCoord = p.yCoord;
  return rotated;
}
```

If your Point class has a constructor that can take coordinates then you can make it shorter.

```
public Point rot90(Point p){
  return new Point(p.yCoord, -p.xCoord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem? Code not working or the result not as expected?

---

In the complex plane interpretation of Euclidean geometry, rotation (x,y) by 90° is, by definition of the complex unit, the multiplication of x+i·y by i. Since

```
i·(x+i·y)=-y+i·x,
```

the rotated point has the coordinates (-y,x), and your code implements the rotation by 270° =^= -90°.

---

In general, the rotation by an angle a amounts to the multiplication

```
(cos(a)+i*sin(a)) * (x+i*y)
```

---

Note that the screen coordinate system is the mirror image of the Cartesian plane, the y axis points down. Thus angle orientation is reversed.